# How can i match the exact text in XML

Tags: ruby, regex, xml, sublimetext

I want to match the exact text "puts" in the (xml file) for a .tmTheme file for sublime text but I've come here as my last resort. I don't really know about regex please help.

i'm trying to match the `puts` Ruby print keyword. for example:

```
puts "cat"
```

output

```
cat
```

My main aim is to only highlight the puts keyword as i can't find any other way to highlight its scope. It's for a syntax highlighting package.

the seventh line with the `--- <> ---` is where i'm struggling with. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>output</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.ruby</string>
    <key>match</key>
    --- <string>>p[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)s</string> ---
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#ff0</string>       
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Are you running the regex over this XML file, or does the XML file describe a regex to something else? To match `puts` you'd just use a regex of `puts`. In JS it'd be `/puts/`...

Comment: ... or `^puts$` if you want to match against the whole text, as in `text === "puts"`

Comment: its for a .tmTheme for sublime text @Mariano

Comment: As a guess, without knowing too much about tmTheme file syntax and what you're actually trying to achieve, if you want to match to a scope of `puts` you'd just need that line to be `<string>puts</string>` instead of `--- <string>>p[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)s</string> ---`

Comment: From what I've read [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html), I think you can go with `<string>\bputs\b</string>`

Comment: It worked on puts but extra highlighted other things @Mariano

Comment: @Tushortz: please expand your question with some examples of subject text, when it's supposed to match, and when it's supposed to fail. I never used sublime, nor do I have an idea of the language you're trying to highlight... It was just a wild guess

Comment: i'm trying to match the `puts` Ruby print keyword. for example: `puts "cat "` in ruby will output cat to he console. My main aim is to only highlight the puts keyword as i can't find any other way to highlight its scope. It's for a syntax highlighting package. @Mariano

Comment: Please edit your question including examples, and maybe adding the tag [tag:ruby]

Comment: So you're trying to edit or create a syntax highlighting file for ruby in sublime? I don't know ruby and I've only used Sublime for a brief time, but from the brief google I had for this, it's looks like this would be the wrong way to go about doing the syntax highlighting? You'd want to pick up the highlighting for the `puts` keyword using the scope, not a regex match.

Comment: @Klors I've used scopes for the rest but it seems the `puts` and `print` keyword do not have a scope. I've checked a lot of themes and I haven't found any that implemented it. It even made me create a total repository on language scopes and I had to give up but i'm sure there is a way